# Randomizing separate chunks of code

Tags: python, random, import, function

I am making a small game where 3 choices appear and you have to select the correct answer. Obviously "A" cannot be the correct answer all the time, so I want to randomize the 3 prints, but also make them definable so they can be matched to a correct answer.

This is the code, I have no idea where to start with it. I thought about defining the 3 different sections of code as 1, 2 and 3, then randomize those.

I want the first bit of code, "which is the correct answer" to be definable to a value, so I can say, if choice = a then... well done correct answer. (I know how to do this part)

```
 input("now press enter for your definitions")

 #1st
 #This prints the fruit, and the CORRECT matching fruit definitions
 print(a, "is -  A:", fruits[a])

 #2nd    
 #these randomly generates 2 other fruit definitons
 import random
 with open('fruitdefinitions.txt') as f:
    print (a, "is -  B:", random.choice(list(f)))

 #3rd
 import random
 with open('fruitdefinitions.txt') as f:
    print (a, "is -  C:", random.choice(list(f)))
```

Just to clarify "a" is the keyword, and fruits[a] gets the value or definitions of "a" from a dictionary. fruitdefinition.txt is a text file with just the definitions of the fruits.

Thank you. May not reply straight away to answer as I am busy with work.

Comment: You only need one `import random`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.shuffle` is your friend.   First select your two random incorrect answers. Put them in a list together with the correct answer.  Shuffle the list.  Only interact with the user (with `print` or whatever else) once you've got everything finalized.

Note that your current way of selecting incorrect answers, calling random.choice twice on the same list, risks the two incorrect answers ending up identical to each other. Maybe you can think of a different way of processing the list that would preclude that eventuality.  I think `random.shuffle` might be involved there too.

The following example illustrates how you can reorder data, rather than having to reorder statements in code, to obtain different results:

```
import random
things = [ 'spam', 'eggs', 'beans' ]
for repeat in range(10):   # exactly the same *code* will run 10 times...
    print('the first item is ' + things[0])
    print('the second item is ' + things[1])
    print('the third item is ' + things[2])
    random.shuffle(things) # ... but with a different outcome each time
```

Comment: I didn't realize it was possible to code in a list, thank you. I will test this when I'm back home and will share if it work or if I have any further problems. How would you group code in a list as well, as I have never came across this.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say the "code" itself needs to be manipulated (put in a list, randomized). Surely you can just manipulate the *data* (the three strings) and keep the "code" fixed.

Comment: All I want is for the 3 'prints' to be in a random order. If it is possible to do this by "manipulating the data" then I will have to look into that.

Comment: You select two wrong answers from the file, then you make a list of all three answers, shuffle them, and print them as A, B, C. Make sure to hold on to your correct answer so you can compare.

Comment: thank you for this. Your code works perfectly apart from the apostrophe over spam, eggs and beans, as this just prints. The first item is spam. I defined spam as a definition then used your example without the apostrophes.   +1

Comment: Another quick one, I dont want the code to be repeated 10 times, so I changed the value to 1, however if it's one it doesn't randomize them.

Comment: Putting random.shuffle(things) before the 3 prints everything works.